# How do I handle Unicode Character “✧” (U+2727) in an R script

Tags: r, unicode, stringr

I am importing a csv file with unicode character “✧” (U+2727).  The character imports fine, but when I try to use the following code:

```
mutate(s = if_else(str_detect(my_str, '\\='), 'T', if_else(str_detect(my_str, "✧"),'P','D')))

where my_str <- "✧ 5+"
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in source("~/TimeForm/Scripts/RagsFigs.R", encoding = "UTF-8", echo = TRUE) : 
  ~/TimeForm/Scripts/RagsFigs.R:28:81: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
27:   select(-mod) %>% 
28:   mutate(s = if_else(str_detect(my_str, '\\='), 'T', if_else(str_detect(my_str, "
```

Is there a workaround for this situation.  I have tried save as with encoding and escaping the character, but I can't seem to get the code to work.

Comment: Try `if_else(str_detect(my_str, '\\='), 'T', if_else(str_detect(my_str, "\u2727"),'P','D'))` as per here: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#special-characters

Comment: @Phil That did the trick if you would like to turn it into a response. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this article](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#special-characters) 4-hex digits can be read by `stringr` functions using the format `\uhhhh` where the `h` represents a hex digit. In your particular situation, the following should work to detect U+2727:

```
mutate(df, s = if_else(str_detect(my_str, '\\='), 'T', if_else(str_detect(my_str, "\u2727"),'P','D'))`
```

Not related to your problem, but I would also suggest using `case_when()` to avoid nesting `if_else()`:

```
mutate(df, s = case_when(str_detect(my_str, '\\=') ~ 'T',
                         str_detect(my_str, "\u2727") ~ 'P',
                         TRUE ~ 'D'))
```

More information on `case_when()` available here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html